# Delay between methods

Tags: java

i want to put delay between barresi and action but it doesnt work

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {//the button action 
  if(l<2){
  if(e.getActionCommand().equals("0")){
      bt[0][0].setIcon(icon[0]);// setting icon to a button
      s[0]=icon[0].getDescription();
      x=0;
      y=0;
      l++;
  }
  if(e.getActionCommand().equals("1")){
      bt[0][1].setIcon(icon[1]);
      l++;
      s[1]=icon[1].getDescription();
      dx=0;
      dy=1;
  }

  barresi();// this method 
}

public void barresi(){
    if(l==2) {  
      flag=true;
    }
    if(flag){
      try {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
      } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
      }
    action();
    }
}

public void action(){// i want to make delay here but when i click on a second button the image wont shown up it get null
  if(l>=2) {        
    if(s[0].equals(s[1])){
        System.out.println("OK");
        l=0;
    }
    else {
        bt[x][y].setIcon(null);
        bt[dx][dy].setIcon(null);
        l=0;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: **Downvoter** Please leave a comment because it's first post of the OP and tell the OP why its downvoted to make it more clear.

Comment: -1 because "don't work" does not explain what is wrong. Is there any exception? Does the code not compile? Is the output different from what you expect? What means "don't work"?

Comment: @ThomasUhrig That's OK but it would be great for new OP to make it more clear. If you leave a comment then OP can provide more information.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to put delay between `barresi` and `action`

Use [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) instead of `Thread.sleep` that sometime hangs the whole Swing application.

Please have a look at [How to Use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)

Simply start the Swing timer and call `action()` method inside the `actionPerformed()` that is called after 2 seconds as illustrated in below sample code.

Sample code:

```
Timer timer = new Timer(2000, new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {            
        action();
    }
});
timer.setRepeats(false);
timer.start();
```

Try in this way:

```
public void barresi(){
    // all other stub of barresi method
    // action(); // remove it from here and move inside the Swing timer's actionPerformed method
    // start timer that will call the action method after 2 seconds
}
```